# How to remove them with jQuery GalleryView plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleryview

I'm using the jQuery [GalleryView](http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview) plugin, and I want to remove the arrow that slides along the thumbnails when the transitions take place.

I can't figure out how to remove this (tried using the 'nav_theme' configuration option but no luck).

Does anybody know how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
#pointer {
    display: none;
}
```

Or do it in javascript if you want:

```
$('#pointer').hide();
```

You could also try:

```
$('#pointer').remove();
```

The pointer seems to have an ID of `#pointer` by default, so one of these should do it for you.